# How to quickly get the match result of a list of strings to a list of patterns in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

Now I have a list of pattern:

```
list1 = ['a[0-9]+', 'b[a-z]+', 'c[A-Z]+', ...]
```

and I have another list of string:

```
list2 = ['a1', 'babc', 'cABC', 'bbb', 'c1', ...]
```

I wish to quickly know the string in list2 matches which pattern in list1 and return its index (if match no pattern, return -1):

```
output = [0, 1, 2, 1, -1, ...]
```

Now I simply user "for" to achieve this:

```
output = []
for string in list2:
  matched = False
  for pattern in list1:
    if re.match(pattern, string):
      output.append(list1.index(pattern))
      matched = True
      break
  if not matched:
    output.append(-1)
```

This method works, but it takes too long as list1 and list2 are large. So is there any other method that can quickly return the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` that will improve the running time of the nested loops.
By reducing one `if` and removing the creation and append to another list and avoiding the index method of a list you will reduce the overall running time.

```
import re

list1 = ['a[0-9]+', 'b[a-z]+', 'c[A-Z]+']
list2 = ['a1', 'babc', 'cABC', 'bbb', 'c1']

def check_if_exist(item):
    for i, regex in enumerate(list1):
        if re.match(regex, item):
            return i
    return -1

print(list(map(check_if_exist, list2)))
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, -1]
```

Check both of the methods in timeit returns that the function with `map()` is running in 0.17607659999999997 and the original code in 0.1822188 both for 10000 times.
This will make a significate difference in large lists.

Comment: +1 Your suggested refactoring is good -- moving the logic to a function (for clarity) and especially dropping the needless use of `index()` (which will definitely speed things up). However, the notion that "functional programming is faster than just looping" is mostly misleading guidance, at least without concrete benchmarks for the problem at hand (your current benchmark mixes together the effects of all of your changes, not just the use of `map`). I suspect, for example, that a list comprehension would be even faster than `map()` here -- but I would not assert that without benchmarking it.

Comment: Thanks for that note i will shortly will try to improve the explanation. BTW an edit of the answer for better explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through the expression list and doing a bisect search on the sorted string list:

```
import re
list2  = ['a[0-9]+', 'b[a-z]+', 'c[A-Z]+']
list1 = sorted(['a1', 'babc', 'cABC', 'bbb', 'c1'])
output = []

def bisect_match(l, p, start, end):
    if(end-start+1 <= 0):
        return -1
    else:
        half = start + (end - start) // 2
        if(re.match(p, l[half])):
            return half
        else:
            if(l[half] > p):
                return(bisect_match)(l, p, start, half-1)
            else:     
                return(bisect_match)(l, p, half+1, end)

for string in list2:
    output.append(bisect_match(list1, string, 0, len(list1)))

print(output)
```

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't work as the patterns and the strings sort differently. For example, when list1 = ['ab1', 'a[a-z]+'], and string = 'abc', it returns -1 because 'a[a-z]+' < 'ab1' but 'abc' > 'ab1'.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't test my solution properly. Would it work for you to switch the lists, so that you can sort the strings rather than the expressions? (see my edit)

Comment: The edit only returns the first match so probably won't work for you either - sorry!